# Upgrading from subversion 1.1

Tags: svn

I have a very old Centos4 server which is running svnserve 1.1.4. Now I want to create a backup of this server because it has to be reinstalled.

I created a dump file but VisualSVN server or subversion (latest versions) won't read it, they give the error: `int(4) can't be parsed`.

I tried svn-sync but I got stuck on

`svnsync: E170003: Server doesn't support the replay command
svnsync: E210001: Unknown command 'replay'`

What would be the best path of action here to upgrade that repository to the latest Subversion version so I can create a dump or backup from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to dump and load your repository, you can just save your whole SVN dir to tar.gz, something like:

```
tar -cvzf svnbackup.tar.gz /var/svn/repos
```

For that to work, you must offcourse know the location of your repositories. After you move to newer SVN version, just run the:

```
svnadmin upgrade /var/svn/repos
```

and that will take care of SVN version.

Offcourse, it's always a good practice to spin up VM with newer version and do a test before you erase old server.

Comment: I created a new repo on the old server and did a dump and load, then I copied the repo over to visualsvn and ran the upgrade, that seemed to work!